# Android SeekbarPreference

Tags: android, volume, android-preferences

for my application, i want to write a custom DialogPreference to make sure the user can set his desired preference for streaming music.

Looking for solutions on the internet, i found a `VolumePreference` as an implementation of a `SeekbarPreference` coming from the Android Project here: http://hi-android.info/src/android/preference/VolumePreference.java.html

Looking into the API I wondered why I couldn´t find anything like SeekBarPreference. Why this?

Using the Android? VolumePreference, the dialog really pops up and plays some music, but it seems to be much to silent.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looking into the API I wondered why I couldn´t find anything like SeekBarPreference. Why this?

The class is in Android, but [it is marked with the `@hide` annotation](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/preference/SeekBarPreference.java), indicating that it is not part of the SDK. Most likely, there are some lingering API issues with it that they might clean up someday before making it available.

> Can anybody help me?

You are welcome to copy the `SeekBarPreference` and [`VolumePreference`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/preference/VolumePreference.java) (also marked with `@hide`) into your own project, move them into your own package, and modify them to suit.